# Using case statements for generating commission

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a table with a field ClearPrincipalLOC. I need to generate commission on the basis of ClearPrincipalLOC values.

If ClearPrincipalLOC < 25000.99 then Commission = 125

if CLearPrincipalLOC < 50000.99 then commission = 150

if ClearPrincipalLOC < 75000.99 then commission = 175

and so on.

at the end I need to display the report using crystal reports where all the commission and ClearPrincipalLOC is grouped by AccountNo.

I dont have any column of commission in database. there is only ClearPrincipalLOC and AccountNo. column

My storedprocedure to display report is under:

select AccountNo, SUM(ClearPrincipalLOC)as PrincipalAmount, SUM(commission) as Commission
from WU_mainTable 
Group by AccountNo

Please Help me to get commission values using case statement or if then statement so i can sum the whole commission grouped by Accountno and display on crystal report

Comment: A better approach may be to add a *table* with `LowerBound, UpperBound, Commision` which you can do a join to, rather than a long `CASE` expression.

Comment: But i dont have values for commission column. first i  need to gennerate commission

Comment: Um. The first row is `0,25000.99,125`. The second row is `25001,50000.99,150`. The third row is `50001,75000.99,175`. Get the idea?

Comment: im sorry but i really didnt get the idea :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// {@Commmission}
Select {table.ClearPrincipalLOC}
Case Is < 25000.99: 125
Case Is < 50000.99: 150
Case Is < 75000.99: 175
Default: 0
```

Comment: is it a correct syntax? it gives me syntax error. do i need to make a column of commission in database?

Comment: The query is working fine with crystal reports formula field but it does not work as a stored procedure why?

Comment: My example is Crystal Reports' formula syntax.  You will need to translate it to T/SQL to work in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this as a `CASE` statement, I'd do it using a table:

```
declare @CommissionRanges table (
    LowBound decimal(18,2) not null,
    HighBound decimal(18,2) not null,
    CommissionRate decimal(18,2) not null
)
insert into @CommissionRanges (LowBound,HighBound,CommissionRate) values
(0,25000.99,125),
(25001,50000.99,150),
(50001,75000.99,175)

select AccountNo, SUM(ClearPrincipalLOC)as PrincipalAmount, SUM(cr.CommissionRate) as Commission
from WU_mainTable mt
    inner join
    @CommissionRanges cr
        on
            mt.ClearPrincipalLOC between cr.LowBound and cr.HighBound
group by AccountNo
```

(Untested since I don't have your tables and data)

Also, I may have the bounds slightly wrong - but it feels odd that a `ClearPrincipalLOC` of 25000.98 gets one commission rate, and one of 25000.99 gets a different one - but you should be able to easily adjust the above.

Whether you choose to do this using a temp table/table variable (as above) or make it a permanent table is of course up to you.

Comment: Well, we don't have any sample data nor expected results, so *I* can't run the query and tune it until it's correct.

Comment: let me display you my table structure

Answer (score 0):

Account No   ClearPrincipalLOC     Commission

APK1234567     5000000

APK1234567     25000.65

APK1234568     60231.52

now what i need to generate the commission on the basis of ClearPrincipalLOC

and then display it like

AccountNo     ClearPrincipalLOC     Commission

APK1234567     500000                 150

APK1234567     25000.65               125

APK1234568     60231.52               175

and then all data will be display group by AccountNo

Comment: There's an `edit` link at the bottom of your question. Use that to update your question, then delete this answer.

Comment: @_Damien_The_unbeliever have you got my table structure? could you help me to do so?